# $x^3 + y^3 = p^2$ over the integers

Tags: prime-numbers, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, integers, eisenstein-integers

$x^3 + y^3 = p^2$ has a solution over the integers for some three digit prime p. Find all p that satisfy.

The first thing I did was factorize the left hand side, getting $(x+y)(x^2 - xy + y^2) = p^2$

I then considered the case $x^2 - xy + y^2 = p^2$, which gave me $p^2 = 3y^2 -3y +1$, which can be naturally factorized into $(p+1)(p-1) = 3y(y-1)$, but how do I do anything with this? I don't see a continuation from this point onwards.

Any hints or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the Eisenstein integers?

Comment: I know of them, but I'm not very familiar with using them

Comment: This might help: [Sum of two cubes equal to prime square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3688628) ? (one difference is it talks about natural numbers, not exactly integers). Then there is also [Natural number solutions of $x^3+y^3=p^2$, $x$ and $y$ are integers, $p$ is prime number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310001), although it does not seem too helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the linear factor first instead; this allows you to directly express $y$ in terms of $x$. From
$$p^2=x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2),$$
it follows that $x+y=p^k$ for some $k\in\{0,1,2\}$, and $x^2-xy+y^2=p^{2-k}$. Then $y=p^k-x$, so we can eliminate $y$ to get the quadratic equation
$$3x^2-3p^kx+p^{2k}-p^{2-k}=0.$$
A quadratic has an integral root if and only if its discriminant is a perfect square. Can you continue from here?

> The discriminant equals $$\Delta=(-3p^k)^2-4\cdot3\cdot(p^{2k}-p^{2-k})=-3p^{2k}+12p^{2-k}.$$ For $k=1$ and $k=2$ this becomes $$\Delta=-3p^2+12p=-3p(p-4)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\Delta=-3p^4+12,$$ which are both negative because $p>4$. Hence $k=0$ and $\Delta=12p^2-3$. So if $p$ is such a prime, then $\Delta$ is a perfect square and a multiple of $3$, say $\Delta=(3e)^2$. Then a bit of algebra shows that $(X,Y)=(2p,e)$ is an integral solution to the [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) $$X^2-3Y^2=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $u = 6y-3.$  The first few values of $p$ in $u^2 - 12 p^2 = -3$  are
$$ 1, 13, 181, 2521, 35113, ...  $$
subject to
$$ p_{j+2} = 14 p_{j+1}  - p_j   $$

and $p=181$ is a three digit prime

Here is a portion of the Conway Topograph for $u^2 - 12 p^2.$  A continuation a little bit in the direction of increasing $(u,p)$ would show the next occurrence of $u^2 - 12 p^2 = -3$  at $(45, 13).$ That recipe is
$$ (u,p) \mapsto (7u+24p, 2u + 7p) $$
This is multiplication of a column vector by the square matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
7&24 \\
2&7
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which has determinant $1$ and trace $14.$  It follows from Cayley-Hamilton for this matrix that

$$ u_{j+2} = 14 u_{j+1}  - u_j   $$

$$ p_{j+2} = 14 p_{j+1}  - p_j   $$
You can also work it out by hand from

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
u_{j+1} \\
p_{j+1}
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
7&24 \\
2&7
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
u_j \\
p_j
\end{array}
\right)
$$
write out the values at $j+2$ and substitute some things

[image]

Here are the first few values of $p$ after $1.$  Some of them are prime.

```
13  =   13
181  =   181
2521  =   2521
35113  =   13 37 73
489061  =   489061
6811741  =   6811741
94875313  =   13 61 181 661
1321442641  =   1321442641
18405321661  =   18405321661
256353060613  =   13 757 2521 10333
3570537526921  =   277 3037 4244329
```

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ the same? and how did you get the second equation?