# using eisenstein integers to solve diophantine equations

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, eisenstein-integers

Earlier, I asked a question; this is a question regarding an answer I received to it.

Apparently when $u^2 - 12p^2 = -3$, with $p$ a three digit prime, there is some sort of recursion of the values of $p$, causing $P(x+2) = 14P(x+1) - P(x)$, causing the first few values to be $1,13, 181,..$

Where did this recursion come from?

Note : $P(i)$ is referring to the $i$-th answer for $p$

Comment: After reading your [first query](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933726/x3-y3-p2-over-the-integers), I spent a couple of minutes glancing at [Eisenstein Integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer).  The topic seems complicated to me, which prompts me to wonder (re your previous query) how you could be confronted with such a question without any prior training.  Was your original query from a contest or book/class?  If a book/class, was any prior training involved before you were confronted with such a question?

Comment: it was from a book of questions, so no prior training was involved

Comment: $u^2-12p^2=-3$ is an example of [tag:pell-type-equations]

Comment: how does that imply the recursion?

Comment: Notice that the comment of @J.W.Tanner indicated pell-*type*-equations (which I am totally unfamiliar with) as opposed to (simple) pell equations of the form $x^2 - Dy^2 = \pm 1.$  Personally, I think that you've walked into a minefield.  For example, my number theory book asked a question that required me to study simple pell equations.  I spent two weeks researching it before I felt like I had a reasonable intuition/knowledge of the subject.  This is the risk inherent in  attacking math questions **without adequate prior training**.

Comment: To clarify, not all $p$ in the series $1,13,181,2521, 35113,...$ are prime, and only one has $3$ digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u_1=3$ and $p_1=1$.  Then $u_1^2-12p_1^2=-3$.  I.e., $(u_1-2\sqrt3p_1)(u_1+2\sqrt3p_1)=-3$.

Now $7^2-12\cdot2^2=1$; i.e., $(7-2\sqrt3\cdot2)(7+2\sqrt3\cdot2)=1$.

Therefore, if $u_n^2-12p_n^2=-3$, then $(u_n^2-12p_n^2)(7^2-12\cdot2^2)=-3$.

I.e., $(u_n-2\sqrt3p_n)(7-2\sqrt3\cdot2)(u_n+2\sqrt3p_n)(7+2\sqrt3\cdot2)=-3$.

I.e., $([7u_n+24p_n]-2\sqrt3[7p_n+2u_n])([7u_n+24p_n]+2\sqrt3[7p_n+2u_n])=-3$.

I.e., $u_{n+1}^2-12p_{n+1}^2=-3$ with $u_{n+1}=7u_n+24p_n$ and $p_{n+1}=7p_n+2u_n$.

Furthermore, $p_{n+2}=7p_{n+1}+2u_{n+1}$ and $p_{n+1}=7p_n+2u_n$ and $u_{n+1}-7u_n=24p_n$ imply

$\dfrac{p_{n+2}-7p_{n+1}}2-7\dfrac{p_{n+1}-7p_n}2=24p_n$ or $p_{n+2}=14p_{n+1}-p_n$

(a recurrence involving $p$ and not $u$, which you seemed to want).

Comment: @justadumbguy J. W. Tanner has answered the specific question that you asked.  Notice that the underlying question is being begged : how to determine the primitive solution of $u_1 = 3, p_1 = 1.$  Personally, I would have no clue how to determine the primitive solution from scratch.

Comment: my solution did not use Eisenstein integers, which involve $\sqrt{\color{red}-3}$

Comment: I agree, which I think is interesting.  However, you must admit that identifying the primitive solution of (for example) $u^2 - 12p^2 = -3$ is different from attacking $x^2 - Dy^2 = \pm 1.$  The reason that I emphasize this is that my research into $x^2 - Dy^2 = \pm 1$ specifically emphasized that *other* pell-*type*-equations could be problematic to attack.

Comment: [This relevant monograph](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn2.pdf) is good

Comment: Very interesting article, thanks.

Comment: @user2661923 If $u^2-12p^2=-3$ then $u$ is divisible by $3$, say $u=3v$, and
$$(2p)^2-3v^2=1.$$

Comment: @Servaes  Very nice.  Hit my blind spot.